# Phalcon: MySQL trigger not working with Phalcon framework

Tags: mysql, phalcon

I have a `location` table with columns `lat`, `lng` and the `geohash` of the point, and associated `Location` Phalcon model. In MySQL I have a `before insert` type trigger function that automatically generates the geohash (as a VARCHAR) when a location row is added, so if I put in the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO location (lat, lng) VALUES (100, 100);
```

the geohash for (100,100) is duly inserted in into the geohash column.

However if I user phalcon like this ...

```
$location = new Location();
$location->lat = 100;
$location->lng = 100;
$location->save();
```

... the trigger is ignored (or perhaps the value it writes is overwritten) to `NULL`. Am I missing something? Has anyone else had similar issues with MySQL triggers vs. Phalcon. Would like to know why this is happening. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Added the following line:

```
$this->skipAttributes(array("geohash"));
```

to `Location` object's `initialise()` method. Seems to be working okay.